# FlexSlider iPad/Mac Styling Issues (Big Cartel)

Tags: css, ipad, flexslider, bigcartel

I am currently editing a theme on Big Cartel that incorporates FlexSlider to display products in a carousel. From the original template I haven't edited any of the CSS for the slider but I have noticed that on an iPad in portrait mode, you can see 1px of the previous image in the viewport holder.

Is there a possible fix for this? Seems to be working fine on all the other browsers I've tested.

You can see this issue on the left of each product carousel. Here is a link to a screenshot:

[Screenshot](http://s24.postimg.org/5ndxus7id/IMG_0236.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though this is a bug with the flexslider library: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/1470

This seems to do the trick for Nova:

```
.product_images img { width: 99.99999%; }
```